# Getting input X/X/etc with char X and separating it with slash /

Tags: c++, c++11

I make program build with C++. My program is convert binary to decimal and the decimal convert to alphabet. The input is separated with slash "/"

input example :

> input  : 00001/00010/00011
>
> output : abc

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
char X[64];
int T,d=0,i=0,j;
scanf("%[^/]/%d", X);
while(X[i]!=0)
{    if(X[i]=='0'||X[i]=='1')
    {
        d=d*2+X[i]-48;
    }i++;
}
switch (d)
{
    case 1:
        cout<<"a";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout<<"b";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"c";
        break;
    case 4:
        cout<<"d";
        break;
    case 5:
        cout<<"e";
        break;
    case 6:
        cout<<"f";
        break;
    case 7:
        cout<<"g";
        break;
    case 8:
        cout<<"h";
        break;
    case 9:
        cout<<"i";
        break;
    case 10:
        cout<<"j";
        break;
    case 11:
        cout<<"k";
        break;
    case 12:
        cout<<"l";
        break;
    case 13:
        cout<<"m";
        break;
    case 14:
        cout<<"n";
        break;
    case 15:
        cout<<"o";
        break;
    case 16:
        cout<<"p";
        break;
    case 17:
        cout<<"q";
        break;
    case 18:
        cout<<"r";
        break;
    case 19:
        cout<<"s";
        break;
    case 20:
        cout<<"t";
        break;
    case 21:
        cout<<"u";
        break;
    case 22:
        cout<<"v";
        break;
    case 23:
        cout<<"w";
        break;
    case 24:
        cout<<"x";
        break;
    case 25:
        cout<<"y";
        break;
    case 26:
        cout<<"z";
        break;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

I have used a number of ways that are still unable, and only the front binary can be read.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: "I make program build with C++" - it actually looks remarkably like C code, rather than C++, with the exception of using `cout` rather than `printf`.

Comment: If you can use C++, then `cin` would be helpful to read the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template< typename T, std::size_t N >
std::size_t sizeof_array(T (&)[N]) { return N; }

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    int number[3]{};
    std::size_t pos;
    auto start = str.data();

    for (std::size_t i{}; i < sizeof_array(number); ++i) {
        number[i] = std::stoi(start, &pos, 2);
        start += pos + 1;
    }

    for (auto n : number)
        std::cout << static_cast<char>('A' + n - 1);
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate problems you need to fix:

```
scanf("%[^/]/%d", X);
```

As written, this will exhibit undefined behavior, since it'll try and parse the first string into `X`,  then it reads the `'/'` that separates, but then it'll read the next set of digits as a number without a variable to store them in.  I'd advise getting rid of the trailing `%d` in the format specifier string.

You should also check the return value of `scanf()` since that will tell you how many values were parsed.  Knowing this leads very neatly into the solution to the main problem: why is it only processing the first number?

That's because you call `scanf()` once, read on number, process it, output the result, and then terminate execution.

What you need to do is wrap up most of the code in a `while` loop, and use the following line as the test condition for the loop:

```
while (scanf("%[^/]/", X) == 1)
```

That kills two birds with one stone: it'll correctly parse the next set of digits and enter the loop if it finds anything, and if there isn't anything, it should return 0, causing the loop to terminate.